# php: loading oracle driver gives error "Unable to load dynamic library - The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: php, oracle, dll, pdo

I seem to have a strange problem with PHP.

I've migrated a bunch of software from one server to another. On the server some scripts make a connection to Oracle, so to be able to make a connection the oracle client is installed and a tnsnames file is in place. Connection from sql*plus works.

Some of the scripts use PDO, so for that I've enabled extension=php_pdo_oci.dll in php.ini. These scripts work like a charm.

Some other scripts use functions like oci_connect, and these need a extension like php_oci8.dll. With xammp (that I use as apache/php/mysql bundle) php_oci8_12c.dll is delivered, so I thought that extension would be adequate.

When starting the server, I see these errors in the php errorlog:

```
Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The file is in located in C:\xampp\php\ext\, so that shouldn't be a problem. Other extensions that are in the same dir are picked up without any problems. I've also tried to load php_oci8.dll, wich I picked up from the old server, but got exactly the same problem.

Some answers I found to similar problems I tried without success:
- copying the dll to c:\windows\system
- adding the php ext dir to the system PATH variable
- adding the oracle client to the system PATH variable (was already in there)

The software versions I'm using:

- OS: Windows 2012 R2 x64
- PHP: 5.6.3
- Oracle database: 11.2.0.4.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out and can answer my own question. It looks like XAMPP is delivering a non-suitable ddl with their distribution.
The right and most recent oci8 dll's are downloadable here in all possible flavors: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/. Once I got the right one, it worked like a charm.

Comment: True, XAMPP 3.2.2 (with php 5.6.21) comes with bad version of OCI8. I've followed your link and now it's working! Thank you.  I've download php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip

Comment: @BigPino I have the same problem with xampp and oracle, when i start apache , i get this error ( The entry point of the OCISessionGet procedure is not found in the dynamic link library C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll ) then i checked the error log: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.  Where did you put the oci8 dll ??

Comment: XAMPP comes with PHP compilled with ThreadSafe, so you have to download this file : http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip


Before paste the 3 dlls here : C:\xampp\php\ext\, rename to .old

Be sure you have enable the good DLL according to your version of your Oracle database in the file php.ini.

Finally, Restart Apache

Comment: @Leoh, see my answer above. Forgot to link you!

Comment: @BigPino same problem, i checked the logs and gets this: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_oci8_11g.dll' The module can not be found m\xef\xbf\xbddulo

Comment: @Leoh : Does Oracle Client 11g is installed (Full version, x86) on your server? Make sure you have 32 bits version instead of 64 bits! XAMMP for Windows is 32 bits ONLY.

Comment: thanks @BigPino I already fix it uninstalling xampp and use apache & php & oracle 11g XE

Answer (score 0):

**XAMPP** comes with **PHP** compilled with *ThreadSafe*, so you have to download the file from this directory:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/ …

Before you paste the 3 DLLs to  *C:\xampp\php\ext*, append "*.old*" to each file. Be sure you have enabled the good DLL according to your version of your Oracle database in the file *php.ini*. Finally, Restart Apache.