# Xampp, Windows10, Oracle 12c, php 7.1

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5, xampp, php-7

Since I've seen a lot of posts about this matter and none of them seems to have the answer I need ('cause none of them worked for me) I'd like to ask, I'm running w10 with xamp 3.2.2, this xampp extension for oci8 is 12c, anyway I'm having a hard time making the adjustments so I can connect to oracle using yajra/laravel-oci8 for laravel...

I have downloaded the oracle database, downloaded the instant client 12.2 updated the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable, and nothing works, when I try the $ composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:"5.5.*", it says:

> "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_12c' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c (No se puede encontrar el m▒dulo especificado.
>   ), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_oci8_12c.dll (No se puede encontrar el m▒dulo especificado."

I don't get What I'm doing bad... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: phpinfo shows the php_oci module being loaded?

Comment: Where did you place the instant client?

Comment: C:/instant_client

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before and if my memory serves me correct then you need to update your System Variable named "Path" to include the location of the Oracle Instant Client.

So it could look something like this:

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\path\to\oracle_instant_client\folder

Comment: and yes, I created the enviorement variable and put it there... looks something like this: C:\instantclient_12_2

Comment: @gamn2090 Have you tried restarting your computer? Sometimes the `Path` variable is sticky.

Comment: yes, like 40 times now, I've read that the problem is that xampp is 32bit and the instant client is 64, I downloaded the 32 bit version and still it does not work, I've tryed everything u can see in internet and still nothing :(

Comment: @gamn2090 I see, have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782503/2191572 ?