# Unable to load dynamic library php_oci8_12c.dll

Tags: php, oracle, client, oci8, instant

Ok, so i have the same problem.

To fix it i had to install oracle instant client and an NTS dll of oci8_12c

when i start my WAMP i get this error:

`[20-Feb-2018 13:40:38 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'd:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_oci8_12c.dll'`

in Unknown on line 0

I also added the ext folder and oracle instant client  to PATH

PHP version: 5.6.31
Oracle instant client 11.2.0.4.0 x64
NTS x64 php_oci8_12c.dll

I downloaded Visual Studio 2005 (required for the oracle instant client)

I have a 64 bit windows 10 system

What do I do?

**EDIT**

php.ini

extension=php_oci8_12c.dll without ";"

Thead-safe dll gives the same issue

Comment: I have already looked at many other solutions on stackoverflow but none is working

Comment: Running PHP via Apache should always be TS (thread-safe) so `oci8_12c` also needs to be TS.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I changed it with the same result,I downloaded both from here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.0.8/

Comment: So you have the VC11 of `php_oci8_12c.dll`?

Comment: u mean i need Visual Studio 2012? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: You need everything to match when using PHP and extensions. So if you have `PHP 5.6.31 x64 VC11` then you need the latest version number of `php_oci8_12c.dll x64 VC11`. Additionally, VC11 is MS Redistributable 2012 so you need the x64 of that as well

Comment: OK so i already had MS Redistributatable 2012, i repaired it - restarted my pc, but still the same @MonkeyZeus

Comment: It sounds like you did everything right, I don't believe the PHP `ext` folder is needed in `PATH` but I guess I don't see the harm. I am honestly not sure what is going on. WAMP or XAMPP or whatever have traditionally been problematic when trying enable functionality not pre-packaged in their ecosystem. There exists [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780271/php-loading-oracle-driver-gives-error-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-the-spe/30782503#30782503) but it sounds like you might have found it already. My only advice is to install Apache and PHP from scratch.

Comment: One last thing, did you download the "Basic" Oracle Instant Client per the [tutorial: step #12](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html)?

Comment: I already found that solution yes, also isnt working.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i downloaded this one:  Instant Client Package - Basic version 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I see now that the tutorial says download 32 bit version? i have the 64 version. Should i try the 32 bit one?

Comment: The tutorial says that the instant client architecture should match your PHP architecture, so PHP x64 needs an x64 instant client. However, it might be worthwhile trying the x86 because PHP 5.6 x64 is "experimental". If you are able to switch to the properly supported x86 version of PHP then it could solve your issue but I am only speculating

Comment: Trying the x86 instant client is worth a try. Is there a reason that you are not using PHP 7? It has proper x64 support.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

I enabled **oci8** in **wamp64** after to do this:

copy **oci.dll**, **oraociei12.dll**, and **oraons.dll** to **apache/bin** folder.

Reference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4178182

Comment: that dll are already there. when i run composer this err show
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you solved your problem, I'm posting for the next ones to face this problem.

I finally found, after 4 days, the solution to my problem.

If, after adding to your PATH environment variables the complete path to instant client, e.g: `C:\instantclient_{version}`
and after restarting your web server (IIS, WAMP, XAMP, etc.) you still get one of those error messages:

`There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries`

or

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.38/ext/php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified procedure cannot be found.`

It is because PHP still can't access the files from Instant Client.

To solve that problem, you have to add the complete path to your instant client, but on the **System variables**, not in the User variables.

That being done, simply restart your web server, and you're done :)